# Mass replacement of string values of a cell array to integer in Matlab

Tags: matlab, type-conversion, cell-array

I have a cell array in MATLAB with 1 column and 310 rows which holds the following distinct string values, 'AB' and 'NO'. Just for information 210 values are 'AB' and the rest 100 are 'NO'.

How can I change them to 1 and 0 respectively? 
Please, keep in mind that the format of the converted values should be integer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `ismember` to find all of the `'AB'` values in the cell array. It will yield a `1` where there is an `'AB'` and `0` otherwise.

```
data = {'AB'; 'NO'; 'AB'; 'AB'; 'NO'};

result = ismember(data, 'AB');
%   1   0   1   1   0
```

This will yield `logical` values. If you need them to be integers you can convert the result with `uint8`.

```
result = uint8(result)
```

Besides `ismember` you could also use `strcmp` to perform a string comparison for you in the same way.

```
strcmp(data, 'AB')
```